# Onclick view large image javascript or CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

I have code something like this

```
<img width="250" height="220" src="img/port1.png" class="wp-post-image" alt="1" />
<a href="">View Large Image</a>
<img width="250" height="220" src="img/port1.png" class="wp-post-image" alt="1" />
<a href="">View Large Image</a>
<img width="250" height="220" src="img/port1.png" class="wp-post-image" alt="1" />
<a href="">View Large Image</a>
```

When we click on view large image link , Image should be display large and not disturb other images location.

Comment: look at [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+lightbox&oq=jquery+lightbox&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2.3764j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) link

Comment: If you want a transition you need to add it. If you want the image to appear in front of everything else you have to add the code. I suggest using jQuery for the transitions and google z-index and absolute positioning for where you want the image placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/releases/lightbox2.6.zip

PART 1 - GET SETUP

1.Download and unzip the  Lightbox from above.

2.Look inside the js folder to find jquery-1.10.2.min.js and lightbox-2.6.min.js and load both of these files from your html page. Load jQuery first:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

3.Look inside the css folder to find lightbox.css and load it from your html page:

```
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

4.Look inside the img folder to find close.png, loading.gif, prev.png, and next.png. These files are used in lightbox.css. By default, lightbox.css will look for these images in a folder called img.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PART 2 - TURN IT ON

1.Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to activate Lightbox. For the value of the attribute, use a unique name for each image. For example:

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
```

Optional: Set the title attribute if you want to show a caption.

2.If you have a group of related images that you would like to combine into a set, use the same data-lightbox attribute value for all of the images. For example:

```
<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #2</a>
<a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #3</a>
<a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) jQuery plugin for these purposes. You can use the old free 1.34 version for simple purposes too, no need for pro license. You can also find a lot of examples etc. on the linked site.